# X removed from Y

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Does "**X removed from Y**" as a general rule mean "X minus (without) Y" i.e. does "What is femininity removed from motherhood" in the following text mean "What is femininity minus (without) motherhood"?

Text:

> What is the woman when she no longer fits into this economy? What is
>   femininity removed from motherhood? These would be questions that
>   Kelly would take up in her next ethnographic-style work – the Corpus
>   section of Interim, 1984–89; however, Post-Partum Document also raises
>   the issue of the representability of female desire per se (Art and
>   Psychoanalysis by Maria Walsh).

Comment: That is what it would appear to mean. However the question does not seem entirely one about the English language - more something for "gender studies", or "politics of gender" etc.

Comment: 'When you remove motherhood from womankind, what is one left with?'

Comment: Consider what is being removed from what: “Remove the key from the lock” “remove the pot from the stove” “remove the spot from the shirt” ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is that what it is saying? I am not at all clear.  And unless we are given a significantly larger extract of the text I don't think we have any way of knowing.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite.

Normally, the form *X removed from Y* talks about X being part of Y in the past, but has now come out on its own.

But in your context, it relates to X *interacting* with Y in the past, and now being considered with Y excluded from its background.

Put differently, it isn’t removing Y from X, which would be a reversal of the statement, but a removal of Y from the *background* of X.

In the context of your specific quote, femininity can be thought of as having different aspects to its background: motherhood, love, career, family, etc.

The author poses the question (possibly rhetorical) of what femininity would look like or would be if it no longer implicitly referenced motherhood.